# Eigenvalues of an inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Given the 2x2 matrix A has a negative eigenvalue -2 and a positive eigenvalue 6, then find the eigenvalues of the inverse matrix A

From my studies, Inverse of a matrix can be found by: $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{| A|}C^T$

I don't understand how will the eigenvalues be affected by this and I don't understand why the answer is $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{6} $

What is the concept that I am missing here?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible then $Av=\lambda v\Leftrightarrow \lambda^{-1}v= A^{-1}v$

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking way to complicated. Let $v_{-2}$ and $v_6$ be the corresponding eigenvectors. Then:
$$
Av_{-2} = -2v 
$$
Multiply with inverse:
$$
v_{-2} = -2A^{-1}v
$$
Rearrange:
$$
A^{-1}v = -\frac{1}{2}v
$$
Same argument works for $v_6$. This also holds true for matrices of any size.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is assumed to have nonzero eigenvalues it is invertible. Thus,
$$Ax = \lambda x \\ \implies A^{-1}Ax = \lambda A^{-1}x \\
\implies \frac{1}{\lambda}x = A^{-1}x.$$
In other words, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue for $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is as follows:

$A$ having two distinct eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable with

$$A=P^{-1}DP \ \text{where} \ D=diag(-2,6)$$

implying

$$A^{-1}=P^{-1}D^{-1}P \ \text{where} \ D^{-1}=diag(-1/2,1/6).$$

Answer (score 0):

For a $ \ 2 \times 2 \ $ matrix $ \ \mathbf{A} \ = \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\
c & d \end{array} \right] \ \ , \ $ the characteristic equation for its eigenvalues is $ \ \lambda^2 \ - \ (a + d)·\lambda \ + \ (ad - bc)\  = \ \lambda^2 \ - \ T·\lambda \ + \ D \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ with $ \ T \ $ being the trace of $ \ \mathbf{A} \ $ and $ \ D \ = \ \det \mathbf{A} \ \ . \ $  Since we have
$$ \ \mathbf{A}^{-1} \ = \ \frac{1}{D} \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} d & -b \\
-c & a \end{array} \right] \ \ , \ $$
the characteristic equation for the eigenvalues $ \ \lambda' \ $ of this inverse matrix is
$$ \lambda'^2 \ - \ \frac{(a + d)}{D}·\lambda' \ + \ \frac{(ad - bc)}{D^2}\  = \ \lambda'^2 \ - \ \frac{T}{D}·\lambda' \ + \ \frac{1}{D} \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$

Multiplying this last equation through by $ \ D \ $ does not alter its solutions, so the new characteristic equation can be expressed as $ \ D·\lambda'^2 \ - \ T·\lambda' \ + \ 1 \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ $  But this has just the *reciprocal polynomial* of that in the original characteristic equation, so its solutions are the reciprocals of the original eigenvalues. [Note the first paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) . ]